# want to display exactly 2 digits after floating point

Tags: php, floating-point

I want to convert floating value of 8 digits after floating point in to 2 digits after floating point ..

Eg. $a = 2.200000  ==> 2.20

I am using round function of php. Problem with round is if my number is 2.200000 it converts number in 2.2 . I want output as 2.20

Can any one suggest the possible way?

Actual code

```
$price = sprintf ("%.2f", round(($opt->price_value + ($opt->price_value * $this->row->prices[0]->taxes[0]->tax_rate)), 2));
```

i want out put like if my floating number is 2.2000000. then it should return me 2.20. but right now it is returning me 2.2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This does what I think you are asking for:

```
<?php

$a = 2.20032324;
$f = sprintf ("%.2f", $a);
echo "$a rounded to 2 decimal places is '$f'\n";

$a = 2.2000000;
$f = sprintf ("%.2f", $a);
echo "$a rounded to 2 decimal places is '$f'\n";
```

results:

```
[wally@lenovoR61 ~]$ php t.php
2.20032324 rounded to 2 decimal places is '2.20'
2.2 rounded to 2 decimal places is '2.20'
```

I added two test cases

Comment: @SLAYER: You should remove the `round()` operations from your calculation.  The `.2f` format does all of what you want.

Comment: @SLAYER:  `$price = sprintf ("%.2f", $opt->price_value * (1 + $this->row->prices[0]->taxes[0]->tax_rate));` (I refactored it to eliminate duplicate term.)

Answer (score 0):

i was working on it :D

```
$number='49.099998479854654656516198498465465465465';

function pure_decimal($number){
if(is_numeric($number) and floor($number)!=$number){
//decimal detected
$explode=explode('.',$number);
$first_no=$explode['0'];
$second_no=$explode['1'];
$get_only_two=substr($second_no,0,2);
$final_no=$first_no.'.'.$get_only_two;
$final_no=($final_no*1);
}else{
//normal
$final_no=$number;
}
return $final_no;
}
```

//result is 49.09

regards.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, You can get your result.

```
       $a = 2.200000;
       echo number_format((float)$a,2,'.','');
```

Answer (score -1):

try `$val = round($a * 100)/100;`